# Does Java pass by reference or value to C when using JNI ( more specifically Android NDK)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Does Java pass by reference or value to C when using JNI ( more specifically Android NDK)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the type. Primitive types are passed by value and reference types by... reference. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to Android, but JNI passes values just like Java does, primitive types are passed by value and all objects (including arrays) are passed by reference.  The [wiki article on JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) is pretty good.